# Android EditText Numberdecimal user input read

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a sample code to read user input for numberDecimal input type. XML Code (provided below) Java code to read the user input.
Thanks.

```
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="368sp"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
    android:background="#9E9E9E"
    android:hint="Enter Initial Bill Total"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numberSigned` along with `numberDecimal` (assuming you are interested in positive integers only otherwise `numberDecimal` is fine):-

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

You can also set it up from Java src:-

```
edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

Now to read the value entered do this:-

```
EditText mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String value = mEdit.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually trying to figure out how to convert String to double. I am using double "d = Double.parseDouble(value);" My app keeps crashing when I try to change datatype from String to double to display it(i.e. when I add above statement.

Comment: Pls post your full code (may be a separate question) .. `double d = Double.parseDouble(value)` is valid provided value is string

Answer (score 0):

Checked and tested this code, it works fine.

```
    String str = editText.getText().toString();

    float f = Float.parseFloat(str);

    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);

    System.out.println("str :" + str + "\nfloat :" + f+ "\ndouble :" + d);
```